# How to fill specific array values which indexes are equally distant from before and next non zero values indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

Im trying to change only the zero values of an array which index(+-1) is between other non zero values indexes.

```
Input:
a = pandas.Series(np.array[0,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0])

Desired output:
[0,0,-2,0,0,0,999,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,999,0,0,0,-1,0]
```

I resolved the problem in a very inefficient way with a for loop which takes for ever to complete

My goal is to do it with numpy.where but i dont get the idea to manage the indexes

```
margen = 1
extra_forc = 100
for i in range(extra_forc, len(a)-extra_forc):
    if a.values[i] != 0: continue
    past = np.nonzero(a.values[i-extra_forc:i][::-1])[0]
    fut = np.nonzero(a.values[i+1:i+1+extra_forc])[0]
    if len(past) > 0 and len(fut) > 0:
        if abs(np.amin(past) - np.amin(fut)) <= margen:
            a.values[i] = 999
```

This is what im trying now without success:

```
a = np.where((abs(np.amin(np.nonzero([a.shift(-i) for i in range(extra_forc)])[0], axis=0) - np.amin(np.nonzero([a.shift(i) for i in range(extra_forc)][::-1])[0], axis=0)) < margen), 999, a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got inspired and found a better solution. Probably not the best but it works pretty well.

```
non_cero_idxs = np.nonzero(a)[0]
ceros_idxs = np.convolve(non_cero_idxs, [0.5, 0.5], mode='same').astype(dtype=np.int32)
a.loc[ceros_idxs[1:]] = 999
```